# how can i call method in web page from class library

Tags: asp.net, ajax, class, dll, handler

I have a page `sample.aspx`. In this file page I use ajax to call a handler which in class library. I do some job in class `lib`. After doing this, I want to call method from `sample.cs`.

For example:

`addstudent.aspx` page calls ajax request to `addstudent.ashx` (this code is in `handler.cs`). I am adding student with params, and after adding students I want to call a method which is in `addstudent.cs` for example `public afteraddingstudent(){}`

How can I call after adding student in class `lib`?

Comment: The file a given method is in is completely irrelevant. What's important is what class (and namespace) it's in.

Answer (score 0):

Make your afteraddingstudent method as public static and after that you can call this method in handler as

```
public static void afteraddingstudent()
{
}
```

Handler,

```
WebApplication1.addstudent.afteraddingstudent();
```

Answer (score 0):

//in my Handler class lib,it is separated project

public class gnric : IHttpHandler, IRequiresSessionState
    {

```
    public enum DBAction
    {
        INSERT = 0,
        UPDATE = 1,
        DELETE = 2

    }
    public class DatabaseEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        private DBAction prmAction;
        private int prmID;


        public DatabaseEventArgs(DBAction Action, int ID)
        {
            this.prmAction = Action;
            this.prmID = ID;
        }
        public int ID
        {
            get { return prmID; }
        }
        public DBAction Action
        {
            get { return prmAction; }
        }
    }

    public delegate void DBChangeEventHandler(object sender, DatabaseEventArgs e);

    [Category("DB"), Description(" when a record is Inserted, Updated, or Deleted.")]
    public event DBChangeEventHandler DBChange;

    protected virtual void OnDBChange(DatabaseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (DBChange != null)
            DBChange(this, e);
    }


    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {


        //DO SOME DBJOBS

        OnDBChange(new DatabaseEventArgs(DBAction.UPDATE, 22));
```

//in my apsx file

protected void LNA_DBChange(object sender,HandlerClass.gnric.DatabaseEventArgs e)          //how can I bind this method 
    {

```
    EasySQL DBA = new EasySQL();
    DBA.cmd("INSERT INTO TEST ALAN VALUES(3)");
}
```